# Sort data in API using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to sort my API response data using lodash. My API is: `https://www.clickpost.in/api/v2/track-order/?username=testuser&key=2e9b19ac-8e1f-41ac-a35b-4cd23f41ae17&waybill=3515341&cp_id=10`

API data is like:

```
{
    "result": {
        "3515341": {
            "latest_status": {
                "clickpost_status_code": 8,
                "remark": "Delivered on 03 Nov 16 - Signed by sign",
                "timestamp": "2016-11-03 08:10:56+00:00",
                "location": "MUMBAI, MUMBAI",
                "clickpost_status_description": "Delivered",
                "status": "Delivered"
            },
            "valid": true,
            "scans": [
                {
                    "clickpost_status_code": 5,
                    "remark": "Arrived in",
                    "timestamp": "2016-10-27 22:19:18+00:00",
                    "location": "DELHI, DELHI",
                    "clickpost_status_description": "InTransit",
                    "status": "In Transit to"
                },
                {
                    "clickpost_status_code": 5,
                    "remark": "In Transit to",
                    "timestamp": "2016-10-27 22:18:57+00:00",
                    "location": "DELHI, DELHI",
                    "clickpost_status_description": "InTransit",
                    "status": "In Transit to"
                },
                {
                    "clickpost_status_code": 6,
                    "remark": "Out For Delivery",
                    "timestamp": "2016-10-31 13:29:24+00:00",
                    "location": "MUMBAI, MUMBAI",
                    "clickpost_status_description": "OutForDelivery",
                    "status": "Out For Delivery"
                },
                {
                    "clickpost_status_code": 1,
                    "remark": "OrderPlaced",
                    "timestamp": "2016-10-26 16:33:23.650953+00:00",
                    "location": "None",
                    "clickpost_status_description": "OrderPlaced",
                    "status": "OrderPlaced"
                },
                {
                    "clickpost_status_code": 8,
                    "remark": "Delivered on 03 Nov 16 - Signed by sign",
                    "timestamp": "2016-11-03 08:10:56+00:00",
                    "location": "MUMBAI, MUMBAI",
                    "clickpost_status_description": "Delivered",
                    "status": "Delivered"
                },
                {
                    "clickpost_status_code": 5,
                    "remark": "Arrived at",
                    "timestamp": "2016-10-29 12:31:05+00:00",
                    "location": "MUMBAI, MUMBAI",
                    "clickpost_status_description": "InTransit",
                    "status": "Arrived at"
                },
                {
                    "clickpost_status_code": 5,
                    "remark": "In Transit to",
                    "timestamp": "2016-10-28 00:15:32+00:00",
                    "location": "MUMBAI, MUMBAI",
                    "clickpost_status_description": "InTransit",
                    "status": "In Transit to"
                },
                {
                    "clickpost_status_code": 4,
                    "remark": "Picked up and Booking processed",
                    "timestamp": "2016-10-27 22:15:13+00:00",
                    "location": "SOUTH DELHI, DELHI",
                    "clickpost_status_description": "PickedUp",
                    "status": "Picked up and Booking processed"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "meta": {
        "success": true,
        "message": "SUCCESS",
        "status": 200
    }
}
```

js file is:

```
  var username="testuser";
  var key ="2e9b19ac-8e1f-41ac-a35b-4cd23f41ae17";
  var waybill ="3515341";
  var cp_id = "10";
$http({
    url: "https://www.clickpost.in/api/v2/track-order/",
    params: {
      username:username,
      key:key,
      waybill:waybill,
      cp_id:cp_id
  },
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(response){
      $scope.track = response.data;

      var sortData = response.data;
      sortData = _.sortBy(sortData, ['clickpost_status_code']);
      console.log(sortData);

      $log.info(response);
      // console.log(response.data);
  }, function error(response) {
        // $scope.error = response.data;
        $scope.error = "wrong";
        $log.info(response);
    });
```

Need to fetch data on the basis of "clickpost_status_code" so that could show my tracking order status. Please suggest me how can I do that.

Comment: Assuming `response.data` is the response you've posted above, what you need to sort is the array accessed via: `response.data.result['3515341'].scans`. Google how to access nested properties in JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming response.data is the payload:

```
var sorted = response.data.result[3515341].scans.sort(function(a,b){  
    return a.clickpost_status_code - b.clickpost_status_code;
})
```